# Updates list in haskell to remove duplication

Tags: haskell, database

The task in question allows a user to re-rate a film such that only the latest rating from the user should remain in the database. 
Initially I solved this problem in a very basic manor?

This was my result:

```
type Rating = (String, Int)
type Film = (String, String, Int, [Rating])
--Example ("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982, [("Amy",5),("Bill",8)])
```

where the functions:

```
--Find selected film, isolate into new List
getFilm :: String -> [Film] -> [(Film)]
getFilm search aFilm = [(title,dir,year,ratings) | (title,dir,year,ratings) <- aFilm, search == title]

--Update the new film and pull details for amendment, STORE
pullTitle :: [(Film)] -> String
pullTitle [(title,_,_,_)] = title

pullDirector :: [(Film)] -> String
pullDirector [(_,director,_,_)] = director

pullYear :: [(Film)] -> Int
pullYear [(_,_,year,_)] = year

pullRatings :: [(Film)] -> [Rating]
pullRatings [(_,_,_,rating)] = rating

newRatings :: [Rating] -> Rating -> [Rating]
newRatings oldRatings (newUser,newRate) = [(user,rate) | (user,rate) <- oldRatings, user /= newUser] ++ [(newUser,newRate)]

--Database without selected film
updateDatabase :: String -> [Film] -> [(Film)]
updateDatabase search aFilm = [(title,dir,year,ratings) | (title,dir,year,ratings) <- aFilm, search /= title]

--Adds new film to a database
updatedFilm :: String -> String -> Int -> [Rating] -> [Film] -> [Film]
updatedFilm name director yearOfRel ratings database = database ++ [(name,director,yearOfRel,ratings)]

--Add new film to updated Database
formulateFilm :: [(Film)] -> [(Film)] -> Rating -> [(Film)]
formulateFilm soloFilm updatedFilms updateRating = updatedFilm (pullTitle soloFilm) (pullDirector soloFilm) (pullYear soloFilm) (newRatings (pullRatings soloFilm) updateRating) updatedFilms

--Compiling to for finalcome
rateMovie :: String -> Rating -> [Film] -> [(Film)]
rateMovie mTitle newRating oldDatabase = formulateFilm (getFilm mTitle oldDatabase) (updateDatabase mTitle oldDatabase) newRating
```

I have changed the following functions to make use of filters:

```
getFilm :: String -> [Film]
getFilm search = filter(\(title,_,_,_) -> search == title) testDatabase

updateDatabase :: String -> [Film]
updateDatabase search = filter(\(title,_,_,_) -> search /= title) testDatabase
```

Could someone advise me on how I would use maps to get the selected films data from `getFilm :: String -> [Film]`, similar to the (pull*) functions?

Comment: and ofcourse always open to improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use [records](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes#Named_Fields_.28Record_Syntax.29) instead of tuples here:

```
data Rating = Rating
  { user :: String
  , rate :: Int
  } deriving Show

data Film = Film
  { title    :: String
  , director :: String
  , year     :: Int
  , ratings  :: [Rating]
  } deriving Show
```

Thus you get self documenting code and all of `pull*` functions for free (for each field compiler generates accessor function with the same name).

This also leads to more concise implementation of other functions:

```
-- Find films by name
getFilm :: String -> [Film] -> [Film]
getFilm search = filter ((== search) . title)
```

Note that in Haskell there is no single element tuple, so parentheses around `Film` are redundant (`[Film]` but not `[(Film)]`).

```
newRating :: Rating -> [Rating] -> [Rating]
newRating r = (r :) . filter ((/=user r) . user)
```

I switched arguments in `newRating` because this allows to define function more concisely and it is also correlates with [update](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:update)/[insert](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:insert) from `Data.Map`: they have collection as a last argument.

Now it is possible to skip directly to `rateMovie` and implement it in couple of lines:

```
rateMovie :: String -> Rating -> [Film] -> [Film]
rateMovie mTitle nRating database
  = [m {ratings = newRating nRating (ratings m)} | m <- matchingMovies]
  ++ database'
  where
    (matchingMovies, database') = partition ((==mTitle).title) database
```

(Btw, why "movie"? we were talking about "films" all the way.)

I'm using [partition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition) from `Data.List` to *extract* matching movie(s) from database.

Also there is funny syntax I'm using to update movies:

```
m {ratings = ...}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes#Named_Fields_.28Record_Syntax.29).

And of course it is better to use `Data.Map` instead of simple lists if the code is full of lookups.